# GNSS module do not working with raspberry pi, but working on pc

Tags: usb, python-3, uart, usb-power, gps

I have an error with my GNSS module. I use it with an usb-uart driver, and when I connect it to my computer, and read datas with u-center or in a python script I get continously updated position information, but when I try to read the same data on a raspberry pi 5 device with the same python code (port ofc changed), I get the same datas for long minutes. Altough the datas are not updated, trough the serial port there is much incoming UBX messages, but they contains the same for hours.

When I switch to the u-center I get new position informations (in a few minute), but when I reconnect on Raspberry pi I do not get updated position data, just the NAV-PVT time messages are up-to-date.

**Hardware:**

- Goku GM10 GNSS module (Ublox M10 proc) docs: https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/MAX-M10S_IntegrationManual_UBX-20053088.pdf
- Standard CH341T USB-TTL converter
- Raspberry pi 5 8gb RAM, with USB boot (`usb_max_current_enable=1` in config.txt maybe related)

**Configuration (writed to GNSS module FLASH):**

*CFG-MSGOUT-*

- UBX-NAV-PVT-UART1: 1
- UBX-NAV-SAT-UART1: 1
- UBX-NAV-STATUS-UART1: 1
- UBX-NAV-TIMEUTC

*CFG-UART1OUTPROT-*

- UBX: 1
- NMEA: 0

These seem to be OK, because I get this types of messages in u-center and in python (on computer and on RPI) too.

What do you think, what could cause this issue?

I would be greatful, if you could help me.
Thanks!